# Twilio SMS to Phone Num w/ Letters Spawns new Conversation - Workaround?

Tags: api, sms, twilio

Not sure if this is addressable, but here is my issue:

1. User sends text to 310-333-ABCD ( <-- not real)
2. [My app responds](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response) via twilio with the "To" number as the "From" number
3. The phone gets the reply, but it spins up a new conversation thread from 310-333-2223 (<-- letters converted to numbers)

My problem lies in step 3.  I really need a way for this to stay in the same thread.  I've looked at cookies, but it doesn't seem there's a way to force a conversation to stay in the same thread.

Bonus points:  If the number could retain the letter format (310-333-ABCD) in the outbound SMS somehow, that would be amazing.  I understand that this is probably a translation happening within the phone or at the carrier, but if it's happening at Twilio, it would be amazing to have this for branding/ease-of-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You are correct that this is a translation happening at the carrier level and unfortunately we're unable to change things on the Twilio side. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Is there any kind of meta data that goes with a reply that could possibly tie a thread together?  Seems like there would be something.  Seems amazing to me that iOS isn't smart enough to convert the letters to numbers when matching up the threads...